# Forwarding touch events to a subview send to back ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, subview, uitouch

I would like to know if there is any way I could forward all touch events that are detected on a view to another view. In my case I have a transparent view and a mapView that is added as a subview of the first one and is send to the back. Now the user can see it but cannot interact with it. So how could I target all the touch events to the mapView;

here is the code:

```
  [self.webView addSubview: self.mapView];
  [self.webView sendSubviewToBack: self.mapView];
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: create GestureRecognizer at the mapView? =

Comment: I have added a gesture recognizer but it is never triggered bcs the mapView is sent to the back.